# Enabling button based on a validation

Tags: powershell

I am trying to set a validation on the form.button based on the boolean value returned from WMI command. When user open the form "form.dialogbox" I would like to hide "button.enable = $false - Disable user to interact" when the device is NOT connected to power source, OR "button.enable = $true - Enable user to interact" when device is connected to power source.

with the button.click({}) we can write logic to hide/show the button but in my case, form should open and the button should be disabled if it runs on battery.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()

$Form                            = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Form
$Form.ClientSize                 = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(400,400)
$Form.text                       = "Form"
$Form.TopMost                    = $false
$Button1                         = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Button
$Button1.text                    = "button"
$Button1.width                   = 60
$Button1.height                  = 30
$Button1.location                = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(148,289)
$Button1.Font                    = New-Object System.Drawing.Font('Microsoft Sans Serif',10)

$Form.controls.AddRange(@($Button1))


Function Get-BatteryHealthCheck {
          
             
                #$TestResult = (Get-WmiObject -Class BatteryStatus -Namespace root\wmi -ComputerName $env:COMPUTERNAME).PowerOnLine
                $TestResult = $false
                if ($TestResult -eq $false) {
                $Button1.Enabled = $false
                }
           
            elseif ($TestResult -eq $true) {  
                $Button1.Enabled = $true         
        }
    }
$Button1.Add_Validating({ Get-BatteryHealthCheck })

#region Logic 


#Write your logic code here

#endregion

[void]$Form.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: Get-WMIobject is deprecated, use Get-CIMInstance: https://powershell.one/wmi/root/cimv2/win32_battery

Comment: Thanks for your quick response.  I also tried with the CIM Instance but its not working as expected, and i guess there is something to do with the button validation logic.

Comment: Your `Get-BatteryHealthCheck` function is not being called anywhere.   Call it before .ShowDialog() line.  Additionally, if you want to completely hide the button you should set `$Button1.Visible = $false` instead of using .Enabled

Comment: Woh great it worked! so as you suggested I changed the code to call the function before and the button.visible did the trick. Thanks alot.